# Visual studio vb asp.net webpage privacy/authentication settings

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp-classic

I am using Visual studio 2010 vb asp.net

I want to secure my webpages from direct accessed by unauthorized person or only user can access the page.

how to setup Visual studio vb asp.net webpage privacy.

or Is there any plugin available for visual studio for securing pages

Thank you

JS

Answer (score 0):

In short, you need to have some authentication scheme to identify valid application users and then you need some kind of authorization mechanism (such as role based security) to control the access to different pages and/or application functions and/or application data.

See this comprehensive help: [How ASP.NET Security Works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks310b8y.aspx) on MSDN.

For a quick overview, have a look at this code project article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPDOTNETauthentication.aspx

Comment: i knew , need a authentication scheme and a process ... 
im a user of dreamweaver and in it there is a feature to restrict pages for users to access.. and it is very easy to implement ...